# Partition?! On a step function

Tags: calculus

Let $s,r:[a,b]\to \mathbb R$ be step functions. Prove that there exists a partition $a=t_0<t_1<\ldots<t_N=b$ such that $s$ and $r$ are both constant on $(t_{i-1},t_i)$ for each $i\in\{1,\ldots,N\}$.

Yeah I have no idea could use a mini lesson explaining.

Comment: Do some drawing.

Answer (score 0):

Let's note 2 things about step functions:

(1) By definition the step function is peicewise constant.  So each step function already has a "natural" partition $a=x_0 < x_1 < ... < x_N = b$ for which it is constant on $(x_i , x_{i+1})$

(2) If we add any points to the natural partition of a step function, say we added the point $y$ to the above partition: $a = x_0 < ... < x_i < y < x_{i+1} < ... < x_M = b $.   Then the step function is **still** constant on every $(x_i , x_{i+1})$.  Namely it is constant on $(x_i , y)$ and $(y, x_{i+1})$.

So now to answer your question.  Take the natural partition on which $s$ is defined, and add to it all points of the natural partition on which $r$ is defined. Denote the combined partition by $\{t_0 , ... , t_N\}$.  Then $s$ is still constant on $(t_i , t_{i+1})$ by point (2).

Similarly, take the natural partition on which $r$ is defined, and add to it all points of the natural partition on which $s$ is defined. Denote the combined partition by $\{t_0 , ... , t_N\}$ (*it is the same one as the previous paragraph*).  Then $r$ is still constant on $(t_i , t_{i+1})$ by point (2).

This proves the result, since $\{t_0 , ... , t_N\}$ works for both $s$ and $r$